# What happens if you play Alchemize while your Potion Slots are full?

Tags: slay-the-spire

The description of the Alchemize card states "Obtain a random potion". What happens if you use the Alchemize card when your Potion Slots are already full? Will you get the option to replace an existing potion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you play Alchemize while your potion slots are full, no potion will be created. The card will be wasted as your potion slots flash red to indicate they are full.